# How to obtain a concave surrogate function for $\|\textbf{x}\|^2$ for a given $\|\textbf{x}_0\|$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

In one of the paper I have seen that $\|\textbf{x}\|^2$ is lower bounded by the following concave surrogate function $$\|\textbf{x}\|^2\geq -\|\textbf{x}\|^2+2\textbf{x}_0^{T}\left(2\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0\right)$$ But I do not have any idea how to obtain the right hand side. Although I can obtain the first order Taylor expansion but I do not know how to obtain the above surrogate function. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first term on the right should be $-||x_0||^{2}$. Now $||x-x_0||^{2} =||x||^{2}+||x_0||^{2} -2 \langle x,x_0 \rangle $. Since $||x-x_0||^{2} \geq 0$ this gives $||x||^{2} \geq -||x_0||^{2}+2 \langle x,x_0 \rangle$. Now $2\langle x,x_0 \rangle =\langle x_0,2x-x_0 \rangle +||x_0||^{2} \geq \langle x_0,2x-x_0 \rangle$ which gives the required inequality.

Comment: i will be very thankful to you if you could edit it so that its easily readable. In current form its hard to read. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please also write a general method for finding the concave surrogate functions?

Comment: Just like as we know how to find the first order Taylor approximations

Comment: the second term on the right side with your method becomes $\textbf{x}_0^T(2\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0)$ instead of $2\textbf{x}_0^T(2\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0)$.

Comment: This is apparent since at $\textbf{x}=\textbf{x}_0$ both sides does not become equal according to your method. However if we check it in the inequality in my post then we can see that both sides become equal at $\textbf{x}=\textbf{x}_0$

Comment: $||x+x_0||^{2} \geq 0$. So $||x||^{2}+||x_0||^{2}+2x_0^{T}x \geq 0$ and we get the required inequality (as stated by you) from this by just multiplying by 2 and transferring $||x||^{2}$ to the right side. I am sorry that I suggested changing the statement itself earlier.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can you please answer this question also which is also about concave surrogate functions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2677035/how-to-get-the-following-concave-surrogate-function-for-this-function-of-a-vecto