# How to get the following concave surrogate function for this function of a vector?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have read in a paper that for following function $$f(\textbf{x})=\frac{1}{a\|\textbf{x}\|^2+b}$$ we can have following concave surrogate function $$g(\textbf{x}|\textbf{x}_0)=-\frac{a\|\textbf{x}\|^2}{b^2}+2a\left(\frac{1}{b^2}-\frac{1}{(a\|\textbf{x}_0\|^2+b)^2}\right)\textbf{x}^T\textbf{x}_0+\frac{1}{(a\|\textbf{x}_0\|^2+b)}+\frac{2a\|\textbf{x}_0\|^2}{(a\|\textbf{x}_0\|^2+b)^2}-\frac{a\|\textbf{x}_0\|^2}{b^2}$$
where $a$ and $b$ are both positive constants. I will be very thankful if somebody could provide a method for obtaining the concave surrogate function. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll wager this is nothing more than a truncated Taylor expansion around $x=x_0$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant do you mean first order Taylor expansion around $\textbf{x}_0$?

Comment: In EM methods it's common to use a concave surrogate constructed match $g(x)$ and $\nabla g(x)$ at $x_{0}$.  This looks like it might be that kind of surrogate.

Comment: @BrianBorchers thank you for your comment. Can you please write the steps to get that kind of surrogate function? I will be very thankful to you. As Michael Grant mentioned in his comment that this looks to be Taylor expansion but I think this is not Taylor expansion (at least not the first order Taylor expansion)

Comment: Probably second order.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I found it by assuming that $\textbf{x}$ is a one dimensional vector. For this case the second order Taylor expansion at $x=x_0$ is given as follows $$\frac{1}{ax_0^2+b}-\frac{1}{(b+ax_0^2)^3}\left(3abx_0x-a^2x_0^3x+3a^2x_0^2x^2-abx^2-3abx_0^2+a^2x_0^4-3a^2x_0^3x+abxx_0\right)$$ which I think is not the same as $g(x|x_0)$ in my post. For e

Comment: You don't want the second order Taylor series but rather a function that is concave everywhere and that matches $f(x)$ and $\nabla f(x)$ at $x_{0}$.  Maximizing this $g(x|x_{0})$ then gives you a point with a higher value of $f(x)$, and you can repeat the process.

Comment: @BrianBorchers thank you so much for your comment. Can you please provide steps with some details. Unfortunately, I can not understand how to obtain the right hand side in the equation above. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: @BrianBorchers your mentioned conditions are right but I think there is another condition that says that $f(\textbf{x})\geq g(\textbf{x}|\textbf{x}_0)$ for all $\textbf{x}$

Comment: See my answer below.  The key ideas are $f(x)\geq g(x|x_{0})$ and making sure that $g()$ is separable so that it's easy to maximize.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I have even checked the results for one dimensional case with second order Taylor expansion. The result does not match when I compare their plots on WA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good reference for this is Kenneth Lange's book, *MM Optimization Algorithms*, SIAM, 2016.

The basic idea here is that we want a surrogate function $g(x|x_{0})$ with the properties:

1. $f(x_{0})=g(x_{0} |x_{0})$
2. $\nabla f(x_{0})= \nabla g(x_{0}|x_{0})$
3. $g(x|x_{0}) \leq f(x)$ for all $x$
4. $g(x|x_{0})$ is separable (to make maximizing $g$ easy!)

Proof.

1. It's easy to see that the candidate function given in the problem statement has $g(x_{0}|x_{0})=f(x_{0})$.
2. Since

$\nabla f(x)=\frac{-2a}{(a\|x\|^{2}+b)^{2}}x$,

we have

$\nabla f(x_{0})=\frac{-2a}{(a\|x_{0}\|^{2}+b)^{2}}x_{0}$

and it is easy to check that $\nabla g(x_{0}|x_{0})=\nabla f(x_{0})$.

3. Since $g(x|x_{0})$ matches $f(x_{0})$ and $\nabla f(x_{0})$ we can expand in a quadratic Taylor series around $x_{0}$,  The constant and linear terms will match, and the quadratic term in $g(x|x_{0})$ will be smaller than the quadratic term in the Taylor series for $f(x)$ if

$\nabla^{2} g(x|x_{0}) \preceq \nabla^{2} f(x)$ for all $x$.

It's easy to show that

$\nabla^{2} f(x)=\frac{-2a}{(a\| x \|^{2}+b)^{2}}I + \frac{8a^{2}}{(a\|x \|^{2}+b)^{3}}xx^{T}$

while

$\nabla^{2} g(x|x_{0})=\frac{-2a}{b^{2}}I$.

Thus the eigenvalues of $\nabla^{2}g(x|x_{0})$ are all smaller than the eigenvalues of $\nabla^{2} f(x)$.

We can write a Taylor series with remainder term for $f(x)-g(x|x_{0})$ centered at $x_{0}$ as

$f(x)-g(x|x_{0})= (f(x_{0}-g(x_{0}|x_{0})) + (\nabla f(x_{0}) - \nabla g(x_{0}|x_{0}))^{T}(x-x_{0})+ \frac{1}{2} (x-x_{0})^{T} \left( \nabla^{2}f(\xi)-\nabla^{2}g(\xi |x_{0}) \right) (x-x_{0})$

for some $\xi$ on the line segment between $x$ and $x_{0}$.

$f(x)-g(x|x_{0})=0 + 0 + \frac{1}{2} (x-x_{0})^{T} \left( \nabla^{2}f(\xi)-\nabla^{2}g(\xi |x_{0}) \right) (x-x_{0})$.

Since $\nabla^{2} f(\xi)- \nabla^{2} g(\xi | x_{0})$ is a positive semidefinite matrix,

$\frac{1}{2} (x-x_{0})^{T} \left( \nabla^{2}f(\xi)-\nabla^{2}g(\xi |x_{0}) \right) (x-x_{0}) \geq 0$

and

$f(x)-g(x|x_{0}) \geq 0$ for all $x$.

4. $g(x|x_{0})$ is clearly separable.

This general approach to finding a separable concave underestimating surrogate is used frequently in EM and MM methods.

P.S.  I've been asked how you could derive this from scratch.  The general process would be:

1. Find a lower bound $p$ on the eigenvalues of $\nabla^{2}f(x)$.  Then we can set the quadratic term in $g(x|x_{0})$ to

$\frac{p}{2} \| x\|^{2}$.

This ensures that

$\nabla^{2} g(x|x_{0})=pI \preceq \nabla^{2}f(x)$.

2. Let the linear term in $g(x|x_{0})$ be $c^{T}x$.  Then

$\nabla g(x|x_{0})=px+c$

Solve for $c$ by setting $\nabla g(x_{0}|x_{0})=\nabla f(x_{0})$ to get

$px_{0} + c=\nabla f(x_{0})$

$c=\nabla f(x_{0})-px_{0}$.

3. Let the constant term in $g(x|x_{0})$ be $d$.  Solve for $d$ by setting

$g(x_{0}|x_{0})=\frac{p}{2}\|x_{0}\|^{2}+c^{T}x_{0}+d=f(x_{0})$.

$d=f(x_{0})- \frac{p}{2}\|x_{0}\|^{2} -c^{T}x_{0}$.

Comment: I think your answer tries to show that the $g(\textbf{x}|\textbf{x}_0)$ is a valid concave surrogate function and in my opinion the answer does not show a way to get the analytical expression for $g(\textbf{x}|\textbf{x}_0)$. I mean there will be some method to get the analytical expression for $g(\textbf{x}|\textbf{x}_0)$ or is it really a trial and error method (check all the possible analytical expression and the expression provided in my question is a valid concave surrogate function). I will be very thankful to your comments.

Comment: The tricky part is finding a lower bound on the eigenvalues of $\nabla^{2} f(x)$.  Once you've selected the quadratic term in $g(x|x_{0})$ by some ad-hoc method that ensures that $\nabla^{2} g(x|x_{0}) \preceq \nabla^{2} f(x)$, finding the linear and constant terms is just a matter of algebra in matching the values of $f(x_{0})$ and $\nabla f(x_{0})$.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. I have just one more query. In your third point (Since $g(\textbf{x}|\textbf{x}_0)$ matches...) I think the comparison is carried out between the second order Taylor expansion of $f(\textbf{x})$ and $g(\textbf{x}|\textbf{x}_0)$. However originally your point three states that $g(\textbf{x}|\textbf{x}_0)\leq f(\textbf{x})$. I think there should be one more step that shows that the second order Taylor expansion of $f(\textbf{x})$ is always smaller than $f(\textbf{x})$. What do you say?

Comment: You can construct a second order Taylor series for $g(x|x_{0})-f(x)$ and make that Taylor series exact by using the version of the Taylor series with remainder where the quadratic term is evaluated at a point $\xi$ between $x$ and $x_{0}$.  Since this quadratic term is negative semidefinite and the other two terms are 0, $g(x|x_{0})-f(x) \leq 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately I am unable to understand your last comment. Do you mean that the second order Taylor expansion will be exact for $x_0=\xi$. Then will it not mean that we can prove that $g(\textbf{x}|\xi)<f(\textbf{x})$? and not general values of $\textbf{x}_0$

Comment: I've expanded the answer to explain this in more detail.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and explanation. I can understand most of your answer but I am very sorry to say that I can not understand the second order Taylor expansion part. (cont. )

Comment: Even in the remainder we are expanding it in second order Taylor expansion. We say that it is exact at some point $\xi$ and further we say that at the point $\xi$ the difference of first and second terms is zero. How this is true? (The requirement is $f(\textbf{x}_0)=g(\textbf{x}|\textbf{x}_0)$ and similarly gradient should match at $\textbf{x}_0$ and these conditions are not necessarily required to be true at $\xi$). (cont.)

Comment: I know that $f(\textbf{x})\geq g(\textbf{x}|\textbf{x}_0)$ which I think we can prove by evaluating the hessian of $f(\textbf{x})-g(\textbf{x}|\textbf{x}_0)$ but this would mean that we are using the trial and error method.

Comment: You seem to be unaware of the version of Taylor’s theorem with remainder- I’m afraid that you’ll need to review your vector calculus to understand this.

Comment: Is it possible to get a convex surrogate function for the above function? How the steps will change? I am interested in a convex surrogate function with following property $g(\|\textbf{x}\||\|\textbf{x}_0\|)\geq f(\|\textbf{x}\|)$ which is opposite of the third property mentioned in your post